# Xtable_AreaUnderCurve values

Tags: tables, rstudio

New at Latex
I need to make a table in Latex with the AUC (area under curve)values and AUC-IC interval of some variables.

How can I combine RStudio functions as the one of the pROC library o similar, with xtable package? 
Or maybe there is an easiest way? Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please can we see that have you tried? Can you explain better your question? For example what is pROC library?

Comment: Hi,

I am using Rstudio for statistical analysis of my database. I want to combine RStudio code with Latex to be able to reproduce results.

I need to create a table in latex with my database information. 
I have used before statistical analysis (as anova, or t-test) by using the "xtable package". For example:
vars<-c("AmplitudeDistance")
table1<- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, strata = "Group", data = data1,factorVars = catvar)
T1<-print(table1,nonnormal=c("AmplitudeDistance"),varLabels=TRUE,printToggle = FALSE,showAllLevels = TRUE)

Comment: I want to create a table with multiple variables and calculate the area under curve (AUC) and confidence intervals. In RStudio, it can be calculated by using pROC or another package. But I have not found a specific code/function to do it in Latex. Any idea) Thnks

Comment: John, please, can you edit your question and can you make your question clearer (adding you sintetic comments)? The pictures, they could help me, for example. Thank you.